# How can I find velocity vector at position $P$ of a particle moving in a circular fashion?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**My question is:** How can I find the velocity vector when the particle is at the point $P$?

---

A particle is going in a circular path around the line $\ell : (x,y,z)= (2+t,-1+2t,3-2t)$. The particle is rotating on the plane $\pi$ that is perpendicular to $\ell$.

Say we have the angular velocity $\omega = 5\pi\,s^{-1}$.

We also have the point $P:(3,2,5)$ which the particle passes through.

---

I found the radius of the *orbit*. By using the projection of the vector $\vec{PQ}$ on the plane $\pi$'s normal vector, where $Q$ is an arbitrary point on the line $\ell$.

$$\vec{u'} = \vec{PQ} = \frac{\vec{u}\cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{n}|^2}\vec{n} = \frac{1}{3}(2,4,-4)$$

$$\therefore \vec{u''}=\vec{u'} - \vec{u} = \frac{1}{3}(2,7,8)$$

Thus the radius is $|\vec{u''}| = \sqrt{13}$.

**My question is:** How can I find the velocity vector when the particle is at the point $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity vector is perpendicular to the axis and to the radius vector.  You can take the cross product of the axis and your vector $PQ$ (components of $PQ$ along the axis don't matter, so using an arbitrary point is fine).  This gives a vector in the direction of the velocity.  Now scale it to the proper magnitude and you are done.

Comment: What do you mean when you say scale it to the proper magnitude? Also, using $\vec{PQ}$ yielded me negative crossproduct than that from using the vector $\vec{u''}$ instead. Has this got to do with right hand rule? How could I know which one is *the* correct velocity vector, they're obviously opposite of each other.

Comment: I think, after some thought, that was a stupid question. The direction of the velocity wasn't mentioned in the task, and so I could choose freely. Question remains however about "scaling to proper magnitude".

Comment: It is not a stupid question.  The linear velocity is $\omega r$, and you have already calculated $r$.  That gives you the length of the velocity vector.  Yes, you have to use the right hand rule to get the sign of the velocity.

Comment: I am having difficulties figuring this out :/. I found that taking the cross product of $\vec{PQ}$ and $\vec{u}$ yielded $(-10,4,-1)$. I understand my thumb is the cross product. I just don't see how the orientation helps me see if I should choose $(-10,4,-1)$ or $(10,-4,1)$. Eh, thanks for the help anyway. It has proved very helpful!

Comment: Rereading the problem, there is nothing that gives an orientation along the line $\ell$, so the sign of the velocity is not defined.  The right hand rule says that if you point your thumb along the axis, your fingers point in the direction of positive rotation.  One expression for the velocity is $\vec \omega \times \vec r$, so if you do the cross product in that order with $\vec \omega$ being the positive direction of the axis you are done.  I don't see the positive direction being defined, unless you count increasing $t$ to do that.